# HTTP Error 500.0 - Internal Server Error An unknown FastCGI error occured

Tags: php, iis, iis-7.5, plesk

I'm running IIS7 on Windows Server 2008 with Plesk 10. I have website under plesk and a site not under plesk and only on IIS. The website under plesk successfully runs php files but the other website gives error:

> HTTP Error 500.0 - Internal Server
>   Error An unknown FastCGI error occured
>
> Module    FastCgiModule
>   Notification  ExecuteRequestHandler
>   Handler   PHP5-FastCGI-php
>   Error Code    0x8007010b
>   Requested URL http://*.com:80/test.php Physical
>   Path  C:\IIS*.com\test.php
>   Logon Method  Anonymous
>   Logon User    Anonymous

PHP5-FastCGI-php is configured exactly like the site under plesk. php-cgi.exe is located at C:\Program Files (x86)\Parallels\Plesk\Additional\PleskPHP5\

**EDIT:**
Here is my php.ini but I don't get any errors.

```
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE
display_errors = On
display_startup_errors = Off
log_errors = On
error_log = "C:\Program Files (x86)\...\log\test.log"
error_log = syslog
```

Comment: Tried but no errors in Windows logs and cannot log errors in php...

Comment: I've included part of my php.ini. There are no .log files related to php and no errors generated by php still..

Comment: How is that programming-related?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Granted **Read & execute**, **List folder contents** for **Everyone** on folder

**C:\Program Files (x86)\Parallels\Plesk\Additional\PleskPHP5**

and now php is up and running for every Application Pool. The main problem with plesk was, only sites running with Application Pool Identity of a user which is member of psacln.

Comment: thank you!!! i've only recently been introduced to the horror that is PHP and IIS and this has rescued me from insanity

Comment: Excellent - I just re-created a site in IIS which has a PHP folder that broke due to the change in app pool identity. After setting correct permissions on PHP itself all is well now - very good find! Thanks.

Comment: Granting permissions to `Everyone` is less likely to be the right option. Have you tried `IIS_IUSRS`?

Answer (score 9):

Preface: This solution worked for my Python Flask application

If your file permissions are correct, the problem might lie in your Application Pools settings.

1. Go to IIS manager
2. Click on your server's `Application Pools` tab
3. Click `Set Application Pool Defaults`...
4. Set the `Identity` under `Process Model` to LocalSystem

Future readers, I spent several days searching for a solution to this problem. Hopefully this fixes your problem in a fraction of the time :)

Comment: oh my god! as you said, it solved my problem in a fraction of a time. I was about to give up after 2 days of struggling. thanks a lot

Comment: ohh Gosh...! several day.. so many articles and configurations, finally this helped me in a second.

Comment: Running application pools under LocalSystem exposes the whole server to attackers. Your attempt to hide the permission issues can only backfire. A Flask web app on IIS should work without such application pool identity change, https://halfblood.pro/running-flask-web-apps-on-iis-with-httpplatformhandler/

Answer (score 5):

I think better than granting EVERYONE, would be to grant the builtin IIS group "IIS_IUSRS" read, read and execute and list folder contents on the PHP folder.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue and look for a solution for 2 days. It was trial and error.
The error code was 0x8007010b.
In IIS logs

```
#Fields: ... sc-status sc-substatus sc-win32-status time-taken
         ... 500       0            267             4
```

Both error 0x8007010b and 267 (use command `NET HELPMSG 267`) say that `The directory name is invalid.`

**Solution:**

1. Grant full-access to IUSR to:

   - my webapp folder
   - folder containing the executable to be run (in my case python.exe)
2. In IIS go to  -> Authentication (double-click it) -> Select Anonymous Authentication (should be Enabled) -> Edit... -> Choose 'Specific User' set `IUSR`
3. Select root IIS (click) -> Authentication (double-click it) -> Select Anonymous Authentication (should be Enabled) -> Edit... -> Choose 'Specific User' set `IUSR`

After doing steps 1-3, Error 500.0 was gone. In my case step 3 was missing. I think it is an important detail to know.

Hope it help!

Answer (score 0):

Try to find more info in logs.
Then try to find all *.log files in your panel's dir. Those with latest modified time should give a chance.

Logs could be defined not in php.ini only. Try to search for them -- not trust any *.ini files :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. once i try to get on the phpmyadmin page it gives me the 500 error response. To fix this:

Step 1) you've to enable the extensions " extension=php_gd2.dll ", " extension=php_mbstring.dll " , and " extension=php_mysql.dll " in php.ini (in php folder) ( if you did that already then go to step two).

Step 2) create a folder in c: named "temp" and inside that folder create another folder named "phpsessions" , after doing so go to php.ini (in php folder) and look for "session.save_path"
and replace whatever between the quotation mark with the location of the php session you created i.e. "C:\temp\phpsessions"   and don't forget to uncomment it ;

Good luck to my fellow geeks :P