# Flask deployment on IIS

Tags: python, flask, iis

I have been struggling to get the flask app running on IIS.
Referred to a number of threads, articles, youtube videos (the steps and actions are pretty much similar) but all in vein.

After installing python, wfastcgi and other required python libraries, here are the steps I performed:

1. Enabled IIS and CGI in the Server Manager
2. Created a site for my app in IIS
3. Created a handler mapping to add FastCGImodule and mentioned the path (combination of python and wfastcgi) which I copied after activating wfastcgi.
4. Added environment variables in FastCGI settings with PYTHONPATH and WSGI_HANDLER
5. Gave read/write permissions to the flask app folder
6. Reviewed and confirmed web.config file
7. Restarted the server

Trouble shooting steps I performed:

1. Tried moving the app to the wwwroot folder along with wsfastcgi.py file
2. Enabled the following permissions to the flask folder
   icacls . /grant "NT AUTHORITY\IUSR:(OI)(CI)(RX)"
   icacls . /grant "Builtin\IIS_IUSRS:(OI)(CI)(RX)"

I have also observed that after a couple of attempts, IIS stopped creating the web.config file. Even after creating the file manually, it refuses to read.
I have repeated these steps a number of times that it has become so frustrating now.
The application however works perfectly in the development server.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Do you get any error message?

Comment: This is the recent error, that I'm getting: HTTP Error 500.0 - Internal Server Error
An unknown FastCGI error occurred

Comment: I have done everything mentioned in this link: https://medium.com/@dpralay07/deploy-a-python-flask-application-in-iis-server-and-run-on-machine-ip-address-ddb81df8edf3

Comment: I just did this as well: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68171663/16469723

Comment: and the error message has changed to 404 URL not found

Comment: Consider starting from scratch

Comment: The FastCGI approach has been deprecated by Microsoft and wfastcgi is no more maintained. Switch to HttpPlatformHandler and things should work there, https://halfblood.pro/running-flask-web-apps-on-iis-with-httpplatformhandler/

Comment: @Daviid: Just did that once again. Same 404 error

Comment: @LexLi - Thanks. I will explore this too

Comment: could try to follow this steps https://stackoverflow.com/a/65916570/11147346 . instead of the virtual directory you could try to use application folder path